# Golang & Postgres Interaction - Subtract 1 From int64 Table Every Query

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gin, glide-golang

I'm learning to create HTTP API's,

I'm creating a dummy API credit system, as that's what I'm interested in specifically.

This is what i came up with: (I'm using [PQ Driver](http://github.com/lib/pq))

```
if !dummy.creds <= 0 {
    c.JSON(404, gin.H{
        "success": false,
        "message": "No Credits!",
    })
    return
}
```

However, let's say i edit the SQL table to say 50 Credits, How do subtract 1 credit everytime the dummy API is queried?

So for example, if i Query the API and it returns the successful dummy data (in JSON) from the SQL table, how can i subtract one credit, so that i only have 49 credits, then 48, 47, 46, etc.

UPDATE: This is what i came up with

```
_, err := db.Exec("UPDATE dummy SET creds = -1 WHERE email = $1")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)

}
```

Instead of working, it fails to do anything.

What am i doing wrong?

Any answers & knowledge into this would be amazing!

Thanks!

Comment: You can use triggers in postgres for example.

Comment: @mkopriva can you give me an example/reference for this? Wouldn't know where to start, tried to google for a few days and even purchased a few go guides.

Comment: I believe the question is about returning consistent results. It's not about go then. It's about database. Search "optimistic locking" vs "pessimistic locking", "select for update" etc.

Comment: Here is also a basic (but good) introduction to working with databases in go (if you need it): http://go-database-sql.org/index.html

Comment: @Seva That helped me understand somethings, but i still can't manage to pass a SQL query into postgres from go. Can you check out the updated question and see if you can spot any mistakes?

Comment: First of all, you aren't decrementing creds there - you set it to -1. Secondly, you have declared a $1 parameter, but didn't supply a value for it. I believe what you meant should have looked more along these lines:

    userEmail:="whoever@whereever.com";
    _, err := db.Exec("UPDATE dummy SET creds = creds-1 WHERE email = $1", userEmail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted by @seva

> I believe the question is about returning consistent results. It's not about go then. It's about database. Search "optimistic locking" vs "pessimistic locking", "select for update" etc. Here is also a basic (but good) introduction to working with databases in go (if you need it): go-database-sql.org/index.html